# How to convert xml into readable gis format

Tags: arcgis-10.0, shapefile, convert, fme-form, xml

I have data in xml format which contains a child element "GEOM" which has coordinates in the following format

> `POINT (9.9632253030540205 52.9569277022282421)`
>
> `POLYGON ((9.7423702151211078 53.0121955350022205, 9.7434299430377305
>   53.0116226800417607, 9.7419839466114624 53.0117578529546236, 9.7416965815231169 53.0120388635930269, 9.7423702151211078 53.0121955350022205))`
>
> `LINESTRING (10.1563217305953994 52.6132026962184227,
>   10.1562498991917636 52.6133444920414988, 10.1562499164679956 52.6134644695202240, 10.1564744722547857 52.6135953416881534, 10.1566720631912712 52.6135844241491171, 10.1568606616562924 52.6134971580102473, 10.1569414808197767 52.6133989904039652, 10.1569953469126961 52.6132408350926326, 10.1570132855248811 52.6130717740015399, 10.1567528163921743 52.6130281593698683, 10.1564564331277936 52.6130663501461342, 10.1563576580763968 52.6132136013941718)`

I can parse the table into csv or xls but how can I transform this format into SHP?

Comment: Would you be able to edit your question to include the GIS software and version that you are using, please?

Comment: looks like GML to me

Comment: I have ArcInfo 10.0 and FME 2014

Comment: I used http://www.xml-converter.com/ to convert the xml to xls

Comment: The ASCII payload is Well-Known Text

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point feature is a bit more straight forward once you have your table in excel (with your X and Y columns), save it out as a .csv and you may use the [Make XY Event Layer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//00170000006z000000) tool to convert to event layer and then use [Feature Class to Feature Class](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//001200000020000000) tool to convert to shapefile.

The polyline and polygon are not as straight forward, you will have to build a empty feature class (polyline and polygon) to hold the geometry and then use python to write the geometry using a Insert Cursor.  Here are some example links for writing the geometry.

[Writing geometries](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001v000000)

[4.3 Writing geometries (PSU)](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/geog485/node/142)